# Delayed rendering of parent Drawer header inside Bottom Tab

Tags: react-native

I have BottomTab navigator with 2 screens Home and Activity, nested inside a Drawer Navigator. When I switch from one screen to second one using BottomTab, my header of Drawer Navigator hides with flickering effect and same thing happens again when I show it up on previous screen. I am handling `headerShown:true` and `headerShown:false` in `listeners` prop of `Tab.Screen` using `focus` and `blur` of that screen.
It seems like header is rendering after rendering of components below it. This header showing and hiding has more delay if I have multiple components inside both screens.
Snack repo is attached.
https://snack.expo.dev/@a2nineu/bottomtab-inside-drawer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Interaction Manager](https://reactnative.dev/docs/interactionmanager)

As react-native is single threaded, JS gets blocked while running animation which can cause UI to lag and jitter.

Attaching code with changes

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  InteractionManager,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const Home = (props) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interactionPromise = InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() =>
      setShowContent(true)
    );
    return () => interactionPromise.cancel();
  }, []);

  const [showContent, setShowContent] = React.useState(false);

  return showContent ? (
    <View>
      <Text>Home</Text>
      <Image
        source={{
          uri: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596265371388-43edbaadab94?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80',
        }}
        style={{ height: 500, width: 500 }}
        resizeMode={'cover'}></Image>
    </View>
  ) : null;
};
const Activity = () => {
  return <Text>Activity</Text>;
};

const BottomTab = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Activity"
        component={Activity}
        listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
          focus: () => {
            navigation.getParent().setOptions({
              headerShown: false,
            });
          },
          blur: () => {
            navigation.getParent().setOptions({
              headerShown: true,
            });
          },
        })}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerMode: 'float' }}>
          <Drawer.Screen
            options={{ headerStyle: { height: 100 } }}
            name="BottomTab"
            component={BottomTab}
          />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```